# Pen Tool: Can the angle or length of the handle be constrained while the other attribute is manipulated?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

When using the pen-tool in Adobe Illustrator, I often wish that to keep the same angle on the handle but adjust the the length, or vice versa and keep the same length while adjusting the angle. This becomes especially useful when working with short handles—relative to the length of its pair—as very small and often accidental changes in angle drastically impact the line on the other side of the point.

Is there a way to constrain or restrict the length or angle attribute of a handle while the other attribute is being manipulated?

I have previously used guides that intersect at the handle or an ellipse centered on the origin point of the handle to accomplish this, but I am hoping that there is some shortcut or some better way of doing this. I would even happily use a (free) plugin.

Comment: You can constrain angles to 90/45° by holding down Shift as you click and drag a handle. Not sure if that's any help to you. Could you perhaps show an example of what you are trying to draw? I'd be interested in why you would actually need this functionality. At the moment your question reads a bit like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Perhaps there could be a better way of drawing what you want, but it's hard to tell without seeing anything, or knowing the actual goal.

Comment: There are plugins for things like you describe such as VectorScribe, but I've never used it and don't know if it would suit your exact requirements, also it's not free, but there is a 7 day trial so you could test it.

Comment: There's a [cheat sheet for VectorSccribe](https://astute-graphics.imgix.net/pages/Cheatsheets/vectorscribe-astute-graphics-shortcuts.pdf?ixlib=php-3.3.1) which shows some of the capabilities. Pages 22 and 26 in the PDF seem to describe some of the things you are looking for.

Comment: You can scale handles. That constrains the angle. You should be able to rotate them too.